# Python pip error - AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

Tags: python, pip

I was installing Python libraries with pip on my Mac Catalina for the last 3 years.
Command: `sudo pip3 install <lib_name>`
Suddenly, that stopped workinng.
When ever I want to install something I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1556, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1577, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

I have tried this:

```
sudo pip3 install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
sudo pip3 install cryptography --upgrade
```

But I get the same error.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using conda enviroments? I solved updating pip and pyopenssl on (base) enviroment:

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

And also uninstalling AWS-CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/uninstall.html and installing AWS-CLI using Snap.

Hope to help you.